# Use of `->` (the "thread-first" macro) Clojure

Tags: clojure

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E

```
(def step #(-> [(% 1) (+ (% 0) (% 1))]))
(def fib #(map first (iterate step [0 1])))
```

The code above generates Fib sequence, and I want to rewrite the 2nd line like below:

```
(def fib #(-> (iterate step [0 1]) (map first)))
```

or

```
(def fib #(-> [0 1] (iterate step) (map first)))
```

However, the both code failes  when

```
(println
 (take 10 (fib))
)
```

with an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$first
```

Is it impossible to rewrite like these or any proper way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [`->>` thread-last macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E).

Comment: Correct. I noticed just after this post. Thanks.